# How to update data that has image?

Tags: java, image, android-volley

I created an activity to update the data. When other data (name, kategori, or jumlah) is updated, the images have to be added again.

```java
@Nullable
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String,String> form=new HashMap<String,String>();
    form.put("name", name.getText().toString());
    form.put("kategori", kategori.getText().toString());
    form.put("jumlah", jumlah.getText().toString());
    form.put("image", encodeImage);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("edit_data"))
    {
        form.put("id", getIntent().getStringExtra("edit_data"));
    }
    return form;
}
```

How can I fix this so that I don't have to re-add the images?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the new image (if needed): If you want to update the image, upload the new image to your storage and link it to the updated data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).